# Retrieving $_POST Variables in wordpress page

Tags: php, wordpress, post

I am trying to create a wordpress plugin for a payment gateway. The gateway sends a data back on given URL (in my case : mysite.com/payment-success). On this URL I have a set wordpress to email as soon as it detects posted variables as well as update database result of that particular payment.

Can someone please tell me how I can retrieve all POST variables sent from external URL in wordpress.

This is what I am doing at the moment.

```
    add_shortcode('payment_success_wp', array($this, 'payment_success')); //second argument is array because function is in a class file.
```

I have added above shortcode on new page with the URL mysite.com/payment-success. The function (shortcode) implementation is as below. .

```
function payment_success() {
    global $wpdb;
    $this->table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "my_payments";

    mail('myemailaddress@gmail.com', "about payments", "just chasing up" . print_r($_POST));

    if (isset($_POST['transactionstatus']) && isset($_POST['total'])) {

        $data = array(
            'payment_status' => $_POST['transactionstatus'],
        );

        $wpdb->update($this->table_name, $data, array('payment_id' => $_POST['oid']));
    }
}
```

When I call above page manually then the email does get trigger. Which I think is really strange but when the gateway sends parameters then nothing happens.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I'm lost. Completely!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usage

```
<?php add_shortcode( $tag , $func ); ?>
```

Parameters

> $tag(string) (required) Shortcode tag to be searched in post content
>   Default: None
>
> $func (callable) (required) **Hook to run when shortcode is found**
>   Default: None

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_shortcode